# Problems while serializing ValuesQuerySet object to json in django

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-serializer

Im not able to serialize a ValuesQuerySet object to json data, i´ve found multiple solutions to this gap, but this case is different because i need to follow the Foreign Keys values.

```
from task_manager.models import UserTasks
data=UserTasks.objects.filter(user__username="root",server_id=2).values("server_id__mnemonic")
```

The previous query returns something like this:

```
>>> print data
[{'server_id__mnemonic': u'lol'}, {'server_id__mnemonic': u'lol'}, {'server_id__mnemonic': u'lol'},.......]
```

But when I try to serialize it to JSON format raises the next exception:

```
>>> json_data = serializers.serialize('json',data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\__init__.py", line 122, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 45, in serialize
    concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
>>> type(data)
<class 'django.db.models.query.ValuesQuerySet'>
```

I´ve found in the official Django manual a solution that [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields): *If you only want a subset of fields to be serialized, you can specify a fields argument to the serializer:*

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('xml', SomeModel.objects.all(), fields=('name','size'))
```

But with this code, i cannot get the foreign keys values i want.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) gives you a `ValuesQuerySet` which you can serialize by converting it to a `list` and using `json` module, no need to involve Django `serializers` here:

```
import json
from task_manager.models import UserTasks

data = UserTasks.objects.filter(user__username="root",server_id=2).values("server_id__mnemonic")
print json.dumps(list(data))
```

Another option would to be use [`serializers.serialize()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization) with specifying [`fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields) argument:

```
data = UserTasks.objects.filter(user__username="root",server_id=2)
print serializers.serialize('json', data, fields=('server_id__mnemonic', ))
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. With the first solution i can solve the problem. But the second one doesn´t show foreign keys values. Thanks anyway ;-)

Comment: how can I use the second method to show my foreign key values? because when I try to do this, they are omitted from my json values?